# How to flash Android onto an empty Samsung GT-P3100 (OMAP4430)

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, samsung, bootloader

I'm about to purchase a replacement motherboard for a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 (GT-P3100) as the original one has developed a hardware fault.

Unfortunately the sellers (eBay) won't say if Android (or anything else) is preloaded on the boards.

So assuming that the boards come completely empty, how can I flash this board?  Would the OMAP4430 be configured so that it follows a boot sequence similar to the one [described on OMAPPEDIA](http://omappedia.org/wiki/Bootloader_Project).  For example, could I load ClockWorkMod via a SD card or USB?

If USB is included in the boot sequence, what tools would I need to flash the system?